# Adding new blank row into GridView when Table source is empty to input new data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When DataSource Table that bind to GridView containing data . It is easy to load data and add new row to input new data. But when DataSource table is empty, I cannot input new data to GridView because is AddNew command button is not display. How can add new blank row into GridView when Table source is empty to input new data?
My code is working well if datasource table is not blank:

```
 protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                DropDownList ddlEmpID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlEmpID");
                if (ddlEmpID != null)
                {
                    ddlEmpID.DataSource = EmployeeService.Employee_Working();
                    ddlEmpID.DataBind();

                    ddlEmpID.SelectedValue = grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
                }
                DropDownList ddlLeaveTypeID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlLeaveTypeID");
                if (ddlLeaveTypeID != null)
                {
                    ddlLeaveTypeID.DataSource = LeaveTypeService.LeaveType_GetByAll2();

                    ddlLeaveTypeID.SelectedValue = grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
                }
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                DropDownList ddlNewEmpID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewEmpID");
                ddlNewEmpID.DataSource = EmployeeService.Employee_Working();

                ddlNewEmpID.DataBind();
                DropDownList ddlNewLeaveTypeID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewLeaveTypeID");
                ddlNewLeaveTypeID.DataSource = LeaveTypeService.LeaveType_GetByAll2();

                ddlNewLeaveTypeID.DataBind();
                e.Row.Cells[6].Text = (grvEmployeeOnLeave.PageIndex + 1) + " of " + grvEmployeeOnLeave.PageCount;
            }
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ImageButton delButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtDelete");
                delButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.originalcolor=this.style.backgroundColor;" + " this.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='#f4a396'; if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) return true; else {this.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=this.originalcolor; return false;}");
            }
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
            {
                TextBox txtNewLeaveDate = (TextBox)grvEmployeeOnLeave.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewLeaveDate");
                TextBox txtNewNotes = (TextBox)grvEmployeeOnLeave.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewNotes");
                DropDownList ddlNewEmpID = (DropDownList)grvEmployeeOnLeave.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewEmpID");
                DropDownList ddlNewLeaveTypeID = (DropDownList)grvEmployeeOnLeave.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewLeaveTypeID");

                Data.EmployeeOnLeave obj = new Data.EmployeeOnLeave();
                obj.LeaveDate = txtNewLeaveDate.Text;
                obj.Notes = txtNewNotes.Text;
                obj.EmpID = ddlNewEmpID.SelectedValue;
                obj.LeaveTypeID = ddlNewLeaveTypeID.SelectedValue;
                EmployeeOnLeaveService.EmployeeOnLeave_Insert(obj);
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grvEmployeeOnLeave.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grvEmployeeOnLeave.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrid();
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtLeaveDate = (TextBox)grvEmployeeOnLeave.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLeaveDate");
            DropDownList ddlEmpID = (DropDownList)grvEmployeeOnLeave.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlEmpID");
            DropDownList ddlLeaveTypeID = (DropDownList)grvEmployeeOnLeave.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlLeaveTypeID");
            TextBox txtNotes = (TextBox)grvEmployeeOnLeave.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNotes");

            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                Data.EmployeeOnLeave obj = new Data.EmployeeOnLeave();
                string Id = grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
                obj.Id = Id;
                obj.LeaveDate = txtLeaveDate.Text;
                obj.EmpID = ddlEmpID.SelectedValue;
                obj.LeaveTypeID = ddlLeaveTypeID.SelectedValue;
                obj.Notes = txtNotes.Text;
                EmployeeOnLeaveService.EmployeeOnLeave_Update(obj);
            }
            grvEmployeeOnLeave.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrid();
        }
        protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            string Id = grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
            EmployeeOnLeaveService.EmployeeOnLeave_Delete(Id);
            BindGrid();
        }
```

When having data:
[image]

and when datasource is empty:
[image]

Comment: Did you see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17567/Show-GridView-even-if-datasource-is-empty).

Comment: @Aria : Confirm not work! I followed exactly but it still not work! Anyone help!

Comment: You can put your needed textboxes in footer template or design they in `EmptyDataTemplate` with a `Button` to add new record to DB!.

Answer (score 1):

I asked and I answer lol :). This is work 100% for whom have problem like me:
Firts create EmpyDataTemplate

```
..................................
</Columns> 

                                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td>Employee Name</td>
                                                  <td>Leave Date</td>
                                                  <td>Leave Type</td>
                                                  <td>Notes</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewEmpID" runat="server" DataTextField="EmpName" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="ddl-boxname"> </asp:DropDownList> 
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewLeaveDate" runat="server" CssClass="textnumber"></asp:TextBox>
                                                      <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meetxtNewLeaveDate" runat="server" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" TargetControlID="txtNewLeaveDate"  Century="2000"/> 
                                                     <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevtxtNewLeaveDate" runat="server" ControlExtender="meetxtNewLeaveDate" ControlToValidate="txtNewLeaveDate" Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueBlurredText="Date  is required" IsValidEmpty="True" InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Date format is invalid" SetFocusOnError="True"/>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewLeaveTypeID" runat="server" DataTextField="LeaveTypeName" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="form-control"> </asp:DropDownList> 
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewNotes" runat="server" CssClass="textnumber"></asp:TextBox>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="lbtAddNew" runat="server" ToolTip="Add New" ImageUrl="/App_Themes/Admin/img/file_add.png" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="AddNew_Click"  />
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>

                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                       <FooterStyle CssClass="Control" />
                                        <pagerstyle   ForeColor="black"  
                                        HorizontalAlign="Center"></pagerstyle>
                               </asp:GridView>
```

then:

```
protected void AddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                DropDownList ddlNewEmpID = grvEmployeeOnLeave.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("ddlNewEmpID") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList ddlNewLeaveTypeID = grvEmployeeOnLeave.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("ddlNewLeaveTypeID") as DropDownList;
                TextBox txtNewLeaveDate = grvEmployeeOnLeave.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtNewLeaveDate") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtNewNotes = grvEmployeeOnLeave.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtNewNotes") as TextBox;
                Data.EmployeeOnLeave obj = new Data.EmployeeOnLeave();
                obj.LeaveDate = txtNewLeaveDate.Text;
                obj.Notes = txtNewNotes.Text;
                obj.EmpID = ddlNewEmpID.SelectedValue;
                obj.LeaveTypeID = ddlNewLeaveTypeID.SelectedValue;
                EmployeeOnLeaveService.EmployeeOnLeave_Insert(obj);
                BindGrid();

        }
```

then:

```
protected void grvEmployeeOnLeave_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlNewEmpID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewEmpID");
                ddlNewEmpID.DataSource = EmployeeService.Employee_Working();

                ddlNewEmpID.DataBind();
                DropDownList ddlNewLeaveTypeID = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewLeaveTypeID");
                ddlNewLeaveTypeID.DataSource = LeaveTypeService.LeaveType_GetByAll2();

                ddlNewLeaveTypeID.DataBind();

            }
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {...................................................
}
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

While binding Gridview control, you can check if any row exist in datatable, else you can add default row as "No data".

By this you can get one defualt record into your Gridview, so from your footer to can add new records

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
 {
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            drow[0] = "No data";
            dt.Rows.Add(drow);
 }

  grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataSource = dt;
  grvEmployeeOnLeave.DataBind();
```

Comment: It does works! Please view my answer. I have just found !